# remove a jsonObject using updateQuery in elasticSearch JAVA api after filtering

Tags: java, json, api, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have quite a few data in my elasticSearch.
One of the examples is,

{

```
    "_index": "some_index",

    "_type": "some_type",

    "_id": "AWDpmuZ9u4O0tj_RL7Zr",

    "_score": 1,

    "_source": {

      "avro_schema": "some_data",

      "md_type": "AA"

    }
```

I want to remove this object - **"avro_schema": "some_data",**.

Only if md_type is AA from all the documents.

I want to write a JAVA API which performs this action in elasticSearch.

As of now I have done this..

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = new BoolQueryBuilder();
  query.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("md_type\":\"AA")));

  UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder ubqrb = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);
  Script script = new Script("ctx._source.remove('avro_schema')");
  BulkByScrollResponse response = ubqrb.script(script)
      .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("md_type", "AA"))
      .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using partial-update you can update the document.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html

More specifically for Java,
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update.html